# Spotify API to find Artist IDs from names?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm looking to use the Spotify API/Spotipy to unfollow many, many artists that I no longer want to follow, about 1200 of them.

I've got a list of them by their names, but the Spotify Unfollow Artist API function seems to just work by Artist ID. Is there a function to return IDs by name? I know I can do the reverse: find name using ID.

I've looked in the Spotify and Spotipy docs and it doesn't appear to be doable, but perhaps I'm missing something? Maybe there's a workaround?

Thanks!
Matthew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [Search for an Item](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference-beta/#category-search) endpoint which takes a **type** of **artist**, you could provide the Artist Name to this API, depending on the name you might get a result back but can check that the result contains the name you want and then get the Id of the Artist from that

Comment: A-ha! Thanks for that! It looks like this - by Spotipy - will get me there:

search(q, limit=50, offset=0, type='artist', market=None)

Then I'll just have to do it 50 items at a time, which I've been meaning to learn how to do.

Or I guess there's this:

https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-search-item/?q=tania%20bowra&type=artist&market=&limit=&offset=

Comment: I got it to work for a single item easily enough using Spotipy. It appears to me, though, that you can only look for a single item and not a list, but the function limit is 50, so there must be a way of making it work. I'll have to have another look over the weekend.